# HTK: Optimizing mixture-splitting phone by phone

Tags: optimization, speech-recognition, gaussian, htk

I use HTK to train an acoustic model. My last step is splitting mixtures of the phone gaussians. Normally, I always split all phones (their inner states) in one step by one, then re-estimate and stop when the performance drops.

Now I want to try out splitting the phones one by one because this should lead to equal or better overall result. The way I do it is, try to split every phone, pick the one that led to the best result, keep it split, reset all others, and start over. This takes too long though. I thought of splitting all of those that brought an improvement, not just the best one, and then go to next iteration.

My question is: If splitting a phone lowers the performance, is there any point in trying to split it again at a later stage? Or can I just blacklist it and just try with those that brought an improvement in the last iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improvement from such schemes are usually tiny. You can get much better improvement simply moving to DNN (supported by HTK 3.5 by the way).

> If splitting a phone lowers the performance, is there any point in trying to split it again at a later stage? Or can I just blacklist it and just try with those that brought an improvement in the last iteration?

You can blacklist

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know HTK 3.5 sported neural networks! Do you know how much training data I'll need? I have about 66 hours of training data. It's for a dataset of one speaker in total magnitude of about 1000 hours. By the way, you _can't_ blacklist. Splitting 'b' resulted in worse performance in first iteration, but in better in second one.